# First tabs content doesn't disappear with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use tab function with twitter bootstrap, but it doesn't work properly.

I have a HTML like this.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#foo" data-toggle="tab">Foo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#bar" data-toggle="tab">Bar</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="foo" class="tab-tane active">
    foo
  </div>
  <div id="bar" class="tab-pane">
    bar
  </div>
</div>
```

And coffee script for it.

```
$ ->
  $('#tabs a').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $(@).tab('show')
```

When I click second tab, somehow first tab's content remain displayed.

This is what I wrote in jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/fe26/ER2UG/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there is a typo `<div id="foo" class="tab-tane active">
    foo
  </div>`,`class="tab-tane active"` should be `class="tab-pane active"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistake in html. 
change **tab-tane** in:

```
<div id="foo" class="tab-tane active">
```

to **tab-pane**:

```
<div id="foo" class="tab-pane active">
```